# Randomly selecting subsamples from dataframe using python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, random

I have dataframe `df`. I would like to select the 6 sab samples randomly that contain fixed data (=100) size and does not have repetitive values. So far, I have written the following codes:

```
df_ = df.sample(n=6000)
n = 6  # specifying number of sample need
size = int(df_.shape[0]/n)
chunks = list()
for i in range(0, df.shape[0], size):
    chunks.append(df.iloc[i:i+size])
```

But when I select a sample, say `subsample_1=chunks[1]` then the results are not random but are in order.  Any advice, how to select 6 random subsamples from given `df` that are not repetitive data?

Comment: You should slice from `df_` in the last line, i.e. `df_.iloc[i:i+size]`

Comment: This one is not working. when I printed chunk[1]. It giving me all datasets instead of showing a subsample of 100 data points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: After reading your comment and as @mozway mentioned:

You can use `sample` to shuffle the entire DataFrame and specify the multiple of the size you want. Then use [np.array_split](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html)  to split it into the desired number of subsets likewise:

```
num = 6
df_shuffled = df.sample(n = num*100, frac=1)  #This will shuffle the entire Dataframe
 

chunks = np.array_split(df_shuffled, num)
```

`chunks` will give you a list of the `num` required DataFrames.

Comment: This is not exactly what I want.  Let say you have 10000 datasets, I want to create 6 subsample , each contains 100 data points which are not repetitive and selected randomly. I think what you are doing is diving whole datasets into 6 which I don't want.

Comment: @AnkitaDebnath sample the dataframe to a multiple of the size you want: `df.sample(n=6*100)`, then it should be as you want